# Logging missing REST methods using Aspects

Tags: spring, spring-aop

I currently have a class called "AspectLogger" that logs Exceptions occurring in spring @Controllers. I am using native Spring AOP using AspectJ syntax.

```
@Before("(restController() || controller()) && publicMethod()")
public void logBefore(final JoinPoint joinPoint) throws IOException {
    ...
```

When a controller methods is requested from the frontend and there is no @RequestMapping that is able to handle it, I want to log this case too.

Using annotations, how can I achieve this?  I guess I will need to create an aspect over one of the native Spring classes to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the most of Spring methods (which you need to intercept with AspectJ for this purpose) are protected or private, whereas AspectJ is for public methods only. Other work-around is using `TRACE` log-level on `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping` class. Since you just want to log, I wanted let you know this option as well.

Comment: In the logBefore() method I am actually sending an email to support also so simple TRACE logging will no do in my case.  As I understand it, there is no problem wrapping private or protected methods in an aspect because they are accessed via reflection anyway.

Comment: As per docs, it only intercepts public methods -  Ref: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-pointcuts-designators